# Rotating (oct)icon in statusbar of VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons, statusbar, octicons

In my vs code extension, I try to integrate a rotating (oct)icon in the status bar. Like the git integration of vs code itself when it is synchronizing. But in fact, I have no how to achieve that goal.

A simplified example of a cheap try:"
`` window.createStatusBarItem(StatusBarAlignment.Left, 0).text = `$(globe spin) `; ``
"

Answer (score 1):

As [the Icons in Labels documentation says](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels), you can apply a spinning animation to any icon by appending `~spin` to the icon name:

`$(globe~spin)`

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels#animation) says you can set spinning animation only to

- sync
- loading
- gear

icons.